# Coverity Prevent Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, static-analysis

Can anybody let me know the link of Coverity Prevent Plugin (Static analysis tool)for Eclipse(Android Development Environment) and its usage in Eclipse?

Regards,

Bhavani

Answer (score 2):

Since release 5.5 (6.0 is the current release) Coverity Integrity Manager bundles the Eclipse plug-in with it.

After installing Integrity Manager, direct your users to `http://<your-host>:<your-port>/downloads` to see the update URL for Eclipse and download packages for other plug-ins and packages you would need to run analysis locally.

Answer (score 1):

Much of the information is in customer-only links, but there’s some information on Coverity’s new public support forum, https://communities.coverity.com/thread/1887.